# passing TLorentzVector member functions

Tags: histogrammar

I am trying to use some functionals to loop over a set of TLorentzVectors and plot a histogram of the transverse momentum of each jet using the functionals laid out here:

https://github.com/FNALLPC/scientific-python-hats/blob/master/histogrammar/functional-playground.ipynb

My root tree has a branch that is a std::vector.  I can get a list of jets using flatmap and take

```
jets = events.flatmap(lambda ev : ev.Jets).take(100)
```

These objects do have a method Pt() according to dir(jets[0]):

```
dir(jets[0])
['AbstractMethod', 'Angle', 'AppendPad', 'Beta', 'Boost', 'BoostVector', 'Browse', 'Class', 'ClassName', 'Class_Name', 'Class_Version', 'Clear', 'Clone', 'Compare', 'Copy', 'CosTheta', 'DeclFileLine', 'DeclFileName', 'Delete', 'DeltaPhi', 'DeltaR', 'Dictionary', 'DistancetoPrimitive', 'Dot', 'DrEtaPhi', 'Draw', 'DrawClass', 'DrawClone', 'Dump', 'E', 'Energy', 'Error', 'Et', 'Et2', 'Eta', 'EtaPhiVector', 'Execute', 'ExecuteEvent', 'Fatal', 'FindObject', 'Gamma', 'GetDrawOption', 'GetDtorOnly', 'GetIconName', 'GetName', 'GetObjectInfo', 'GetObjectStat', 'GetOption', 'GetTitle', 'GetUniqueID', 'GetXYZT', 'HandleTimer', 'Hash', 'ImplFileLine', 'ImplFileName', 'Info', 'InheritsFrom', 'Inspect', 'InvertBit', 'IsA', 'IsEqual', 'IsFolder', 'IsOnHeap', 'IsSortable', 'IsZombie', 'M', 'M2', 'Mag', 'Mag2', 'MayNotUse', 'Minus', 'Mt', 'Mt2', 'Notify', 'Obsolete', 'P', 'Paint', 'Perp', 'Perp2', 'Phi', 'Plus', 'Pop', 'Print', 'PseudoRapidity', 'Pt', 'Px', 'Py', 'Pz', 'Rapidity', 'Read', 'RecursiveRemove', 'ResetBit', 'Rho', 'Rotate', 'RotateUz', 'RotateX', 'RotateY', 'RotateZ', 'SaveAs', 'SavePrimitive', 'SetBit', 'SetDrawOption', 'SetDtorOnly', 'SetE', 'SetObjectStat', 'SetPerp', 'SetPhi', 'SetPtEtaPhiE', 'SetPtEtaPhiM', 'SetPx', 'SetPxPyPzE', 'SetPy', 'SetPz', 'SetRho', 'SetT', 'SetTheta', 'SetUniqueID', 'SetVect', 'SetVectM', 'SetVectMag', 'SetX', 'SetXYZM', 'SetXYZT', 'SetY', 'SetZ', 'ShowMembers', 'Streamer', 'StreamerNVirtual', 'SysError', 'T', 'TestBit', 'TestBits', 'Theta', 'Transform', 'UseCurrentStyle', 'Vect', 'Warning', 'Write', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '_TObject__DoError', '_TObject__MakeZombie', '__add__', '__assign__', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__cpp_eq__', '__cpp_ne__', '__cppname__', '__delattr__', '__destruct__', '__dict__', '__dispatch__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__isub__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__radd__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__rsub__', '__scope__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_smart_ptr', 'kBitMask', 'kCanDelete', 'kCannotPick', 'kHasUUID', 'kInvalidObject', 'kIsOnHeap', 'kIsReferenced', 'kMustCleanup', 'kNUM_COORDINATES', 'kNoContextMenu', 'kNotDeleted', 'kObjInCanvas', 'kOverwrite', 'kSIZE', 'kSingleKey', 'kT', 'kWriteDelete', 'kX', 'kY', 'kZ', 'kZombie', 'ls', 'operator delete', 'operator delete[]', 'operator new', 'operator new[]']
```

Now, I want to bin the pt's up, but:

```
jets.Bin(100,0,2000,lambda j : j.Pt())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "functionals.py", line 303, in hargs
    h.fill(x)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/external/histogrammar/1.0.5-oenich4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/histogrammar-1.0.5-py2.7.egg/histogrammar/util.py", line 51, in __call__
    return self.fill(*args, **kwds)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/external/histogrammar/1.0.5-oenich4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/histogrammar-1.0.5-py2.7.egg/histogrammar/primitives/bin.py", line 256, in fill
    q = self.quantity(datum)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/external/histogrammar/1.0.5-oenich4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/histogrammar-1.0.5-py2.7.egg/histogrammar/util.py", line 325, in __call__
    return self.fcn(*args, **kwds)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'PyROOT_NoneType' object has no attribute 'Pt'
```

Is the syntax I am using here correct?

Comment: I can't test it myself because I don't have the data, but this syntax does look correct. Since you can access the object `jets[0]`, what happens when you do `jets[0].Pt()`? What is `type(jets[0])`?

Comment: I can see the Pt() if I evaluate the method on the object by hand.

>>> type(jets[0])
<class 'ROOT.TLorentzVector'>

Comment: Can you show me what the fill rule is receiving? Try expanding the lambda function into this multi-line Python function:
`def doit(j):
    print type(j), j;
    return j.Pt()`
and pass it in as `doit` instead of the lambda expression. Maybe the bad `j` is not the first jet, but something deep in the list.

Comment: It seems to sort of crash.  I get this dump, [1], but then the program seems to keep running.

[1]

-- oops I don't know how to attach files or long comments...

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the data. Try a traditional loop through the data, checking the type of each element.

Comment: ah, you're right, some of the jets have type <type 'PyROOT_NoneType'>.  I am not sure why this is, but probably I can find a work around for it

Comment: This is a good opportunity to put a `.filter(lambda j: isinstance(j, ROOT.Jet))` as part of the linear chain or equivalent `Select` as part of the nested Histogrammar aggregator.

Comment: right, but now I am seeing that I can do this `jets = events.flatmap(lambda ev : ev.JetsAK8).take(100);goodjets = jets.filter(goodJets)`, but if I do this: `jets = events.flatmap(lambda ev : ev.JetsAK8).filter(goodJets).take(100)` I see that I still have object without a type.

Comment: Does your `goodJets` function allow it? When you run that function in a normal for loop, does it still let bad values through? If so, what is the function not checking? (You haven't posted the definition of the function, and I'd also need to see the data to help in anything but general terms).